# How to swipe a page from left ot right and vice-versa?

Tags: java, selendroid

I have tried with below coding for swipe a page.But,it doesn't works for me.How can i make a swipe?

```
       //Swipe Right to Left side of the Media Viewer
        WebElement pages = driver.findElement(By.id("media-container"));
        TouchActions flick = new TouchActions(driver).flick(pages, -100, 0, 0);
        flick.perform();
        sleep(1000);


        //Swipe Left to Right side of the Media Viewer
         WebElement page = driver.findElement(By.id("media-content"));
         TouchActions flicks = new TouchActions(driver).flick(page, -100, 0, 0);
         flicks.perform();
         sleep(7000);
```

Comment: Why are you calling `sleep()` immediately after? Is that so that the user can't flick again right away? One is set for 1 second and the other is set for 7 seconds. Not totally sure, but that sleep statement could be interfering with the flick action.

Comment: k thanks i will try it by removing sleep

Comment: @hasherr I have tried by removing sleep ,but it  doesn't work at all.